# Sending an array of values through the query parameters of a GET request

Tags: node.js, express

I need to create url for get which is going to accept array, how in node.js/express extract array from request ?
I need to pass array with names which parametes I need to back from Person

```
model.

/api/person # here I need to pass which fields I want to see but to be generic.
```

Answer (score 75):

One option is using a JSON format.

```
http://server/url?array=["foo","bar"]
```

Server side

```
var arr = JSON.parse(req.query.array);
```

Or your own format

```
http://server/url?array=foo,bar
```

Server side

```
var arr = req.query.array.split(',');
```

Comment: A word of warning to others, that JSON.parse will be fragile and needs a try/catch in the event of invalid JSON being sent...

Comment: There are risks when your content contain ',' .

Comment: Indeed, it might not work for all cases. Mine was [1,[2,3,[4],5],6]

Comment: The closest are Array.from(arr) and Object.values(arr) also don't work for this case

Comment: This shouldn't be the top answer since express supports turning repeated values into an array. You shouldn't be writing one off implementations with JSON parse

Comment: The double quote `"` is explicitly marked as **unsafe** in the RFC: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt [page 2] with the note "All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL". As such, the proposed answer is not standards-compliant and should only be used at own risk with no guarantee of portability

Answer (score 55):

Express exposes the query parameter as an array when it is repeated more than once in the request URL:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.query.a)
   res.send(200)
}

GET /?a=x&a=y&a=z:
// query.a is ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Same applies for req.body in other methods.

Comment: GET /?a=x&a=y&a=z:

Comment: this seems to be the most resilient answer , but can you provide some link from the official doc which shows this as a baked in feature and not a bug? from what i know, other servers frameworks would overwrite the value if the query param gets repeated

Comment: @anshsachdeva I was wondering the same, made some research and was going to comment here, but it become way too long for a comment. So, I posted a new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76814912/287976 Summing up: it is documented for `querystring` parser, but not for `qs`, although it does work on `qs`. This investigation didn't give me all confidence on using repeated parameters (with caveats), but gave me _enough_ confidence on this method.

Answer (score 48):

You can encode an array in [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) just "overwriting" a field, formally concatenating the values.

```
app.get('/test', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.query.array);
    res.send(200);
});




localhost:3000/test?array=a&array=b&array=c
```

This query will print `['a','b','c']`.

Answer (score 30):

Using next code:

```
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query, typeof req.query.foo, Array.isArray(req.query.foo));
    res.send('done');
});
```

On backend, you have two standard approaches. For next requests:

1. /?foo=1&foo=2
2. /?foo[]=1&foo[]=2

your NodeJS backend will receive next query object:

1. { foo: [ '1', '2' ] } 'object' true
2. { foo: [ '1', '2' ] } 'object' true

So, you can choose the way you want to. **My recommendation is the second one**, why? If you're expect an array and you just pass a single value, then option one will interpret it as a regular value (string) and no an array.

[I said we have two standards and is not ok, there is no standard for arrays in urls, these are two common ways that exist. Each web server does it in it's own way like Apache, JBoss, Nginx, etc]

Comment: Are you sure option 2 behaves as an array with one value in Node? I have found it reverts to a single value. Also I have found the variable name comes in with the braces like 'foo[]'. Looking at the spec here https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html it seems it just ignores the braces and will array-ify any parameter with multiple values. I'd like what you say to to be true - it's annoying otherwise!

Comment: Hi @scipilot, I tested it again using last express js version 4.16.4 and the result is the same as point 2: *{ foo: [ '1', '2' ] } 'object' true* what means req.query is an object with a key named "foo" (in this example) which has Array type, containing the values '1' and '2'. You can test it by yourself and see the result, here is the curl I used: curl 'http://localhost:8000/jose?foo[]=1&foo[]=2'  -g

Comment: Just to be sure, I was only questioning if option 2 still produces an array when you only provide ONE value. i.e. the url would be just /?foo[]=1 which arrives as a variable named "foo[]" with a value of 1. I see what you describe with two values, but that's not how you sell the second option in your penultimate paragraph. If it's different for you perhaps it's modified by middleware. Anyway - I'll test it again too.

Comment: Ah, now I see your point, yes, the result is the same (an object containing an array). This is the result { foo: [ '1' ] } 'object' true  for next request: curl 'http://localhost:8000/jose?foo[]=1'

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying. If I get time, I'll try more experiments with removing middleware and the like. I wish mine worked like yours - simpler!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to pass an array from url parameters, you need to follow the bellow example:

**Url example:**

```
https://website.com/example?myarray[]=136129&myarray[]=137794&myarray[]=137792
```

To retrieve it from express:

```
console.log(req.query.myarray)
[ '136129', '137794', '137792' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Express has a tool to check if your path will match the route you are creating : [Express.js route tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/).

As Jose Mato says you have to decide how to structure your url:

1. ?foo=1&foo=2
2. ?foo[]=1&foo[]=2

The http request should look like this, if you chose method 1:

http://baseurl/api/?foo=1&foo=2

Your route should have this logic:

```
app.get('/api/:person', (req, res) => {
    /*This will create an object that you can iterate over.*/
    for (let foo of req.params.foo) {
      /*Do some logic here*/
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Express can use [either Node's `querystring` parser or `qs`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table) for parsing query strings. Let's examine the possibilities.

## Repeated query parameters in query string

You can use repeated query parameters for getting an array on the other side. It works with both parsers Node may use:

```
> querystring.parse('a=b&a=c')
[Object: null prototype] { a: [ 'b', 'c' ] }
> qs.parse('a=b&a=c')
{ a: [ 'b', 'c' ] }
```

### Drawback

Byh using this method, you may end up with either an array (if the query parameter is repeated) or a string (if the query parameter appears only once):

```
> querystring.parse('a=b&a=c')
[Object: null prototype] { a: [ 'b', 'c' ] }
> querystring.parse('a=b')
[Object: null prototype] { a: 'b' }
```

## Explicit `qs` notations for arrays

The `qs` parser (which Node uses as default IIUC) provides more explicit notations that will ensure the value will be an array. These notations are:

- brackets notation:

  ```
  > qs.parse('a[]=b&a[]=c')
  { a: [ 'b', 'c' ] }
  ```
- indices notation (as in `a[1]='d'&a[0]='c'` generating `{a: [1, 2]}`)

  ```
  > qs.parse('a[1]=c&a[0]=b')
  { a: [ 'b', 'c' ] }
  ```

(There are more possibilities, but those require more work to set up and are not enabled by default.)

Those are great because they ensure the value will be an array if only one value is present, which is not the case with repeated parameters:

```
> qs.parse('a[]=b')
{ a: [ 'b' ] }
> qs.parse('a=b')
{ a: 'b' }
```

### Drawback

None of those notations work with `querystring`:

```
> querystring.parse('a[]=b')
[Object: null prototype] { 'a[]': 'b' }
```

## Summing up

So you may:

- use repeated query parameters to work with any parser, but will not give you an array if the query parameter is given once; or
- use `qs` syntax for array, which will ensure you get an array but does not work with `querystring`.

## Is all of it documented somewhere?

`querystring` documentation [has an example where repeated values become an array](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystringparsestr-sep-eq-options):

> For example, the query string `'foo=bar&abc=xyz&abc=123'` is parsed into:
>
> ```
> {
>   foo: 'bar',
>   abc: ['xyz', '123']
> }
> ```

`qs` docs does not mention repeating query parameters, except [when stringifying](https://github.com/ljharb/qs#stringifying). Yet, I tested repeated query parameters, and it resulted in an array:

```
> qs.parse('a=b&a=c')
{ a: [ 'b', 'c' ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here use this, '%2C' is the HTML encoding character for a comma.

```
jsonToQueryString: function (data) {
   return Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
        if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
            return encodeURIComponent(`${key}=${data[key].map((item) => item).join('%2C')}`);
        }
        return encodeURIComponent(`${key}=${data[key]}`);
    }).join('&');
}
```

To access the query params

```
const names = decodeURIComponent(req.query.query_param_name);
const resultSplit = names.split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a problem when the array param contains only one value, because then it behaves like a simple string. Or when it doesn't contain any value.

Eg.:

- ?arrayParam=5
- ?
- ?arrayParam=5&arrayParam=6

Here's a function that always extracts the param with the given name, as an array:

```
export function extractArrQueryParams(
  req: express.Request,
  paramName: string
) {
  let param = req.query[paramName];
  let returnArray = [];

  if (Array.isArray(param)) {
    for (let e of param) {
      returnArray.push(e);
    }
  } else {
    if (param) {
      returnArray.push(param);
    }
  }

  return returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass array elements separated by slashes - 
GET /api/person/foo/bar/...

Define your route as `'/api/person/(:arr)*'`

`req.params.arr` will have the first parameter.
`req.params[0]` will have the rest as string. 
You split and create an array with these two.

```
app.get('/api/person/(:arr)*', function(req, res) {
        var params = [req.params.arr].concat(req.params[0].split('/').slice(1));
        ...
});

GET /api/person/foo
params = ["foo"]

GET /api/person/foo/bar
params = ["foo", "bar"]
```

...