# ExpressJS GET-request with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I have a GET request, and I want to be able to pass along multiple arguments, seperated by `/`. I want them to be available to me as an array on the server.

I used an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080770/i-need-to-create-url-for-get-which-is-going-to-accept-array-how-in-node-js-expr), and got the route:  `'/myRoute/(:someValue)*`, then:

```
var values = [req.params.someValue].concat(req.params[0].split('/').slice(1));
```

Problem is that all the arguments are strings consisting of numbers, letters and some `_`, e.g. `172394_G_S`. This works fine for the second, third etc. arguments, but for the first one (`someValue`), I simply get the first character. That is: I get the first character of `someValue`, but for the rest of my arguments I get a complete string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to change your route to

```
'/myRoute/(:someValue)/*'
```

With the above route, I get :someValue as a complete string

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I get `someValue` as a complete string with that route, but the second one disappears. E.g. for `myRoute/a/b/c/d` I get an array of `[a, c, d]`.

Comment: because you slice your array with .slice(1)

Comment: remove that slice function, you will see the second parameter

Comment: Ah, of course. My bad! Shouldn't have copy-pasted that so blindly. Thanks!