# Fill array with req.query

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to fill an array with req.params, so i can edit my code easily right now the code is like this .

```
let test = [req.query.t0,req.query.t1,req.query.t2,req.query.t3,req.query.t4,req.query.t5,req.query.t6,req.query.t7,req.query.t8,req.query.t9,req.query.t10,req.query.t11]
```

Is there a way to fill easily my array with a loop or a fill map ?

something like this.

```
let init = 0;
let end = 19;
let test = Array(req.query.init-req.query.end+1)
.fill()
.map(() => init++);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use `Object.values`:

```js
var req = { query: { t0: 't0', t1: 't1', t2: 't2' }};
var params = Object.values(req.query);
console.log(params);
```

Or with `Object.keys` if you cannot:

```js
var req = { query: { t0: 't0', t1: 't1', t2: 't2' }};
var params = Object.keys(req.query).map(key => req.query[key]);
console.log(params);
```

In case you want to retrieve a limited number of parameters, you can add `array.prototype.filter`:

```js
var req = { query: { t0: 't0', t1: 't1', t2: 't2', t3: 't3', t4: 't4' }};
var nbParams = 3;
var params = Object.keys(req.query).filter((key, i) => i < nbParams).map(key => req.query[key]);
console.log(params);
```

Comment: Thank you sir working like a charm, is there a way to do a loop and to add i++ after every t ?

Comment: Something like this t[i], i++, i>20 is it possible ?

Comment: my request is like this ``http://localhost:5002/89EyATXtAyEb96T7z7?l=fr&n=HeyOh&m0=hey@test.com&m1=Test2@test.com&m2=&m3=&t4=&m5=&m6=&m7=&m8=&m9=&m10=&m11=&m12=&m13=&m14=&m15=&m16=&m17=&m18=m18@test.com&m19=&v=4.9.6&hw=6.7
``
I want to take all the emails and not the other query

Answer (score 1):

Actually your API should take an array instead, like:

```
yourapi?t=one&t=two&t=three
```

And you can get the array like this:

```
 req.query.t // ["one", "two", "three"]
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080770/i-need-to-create-url-for-get-which-is-going-to-accept-array-how-in-node-js-expr)

Comment: @taieb yup and thats wrong. you should change the query

Answer (score 1):

Assuming rep.query properties reliably start with `t` and end with numbers:

```js
function fillArrayFromReq(query, start, end) {
  return Array.from({ length: end - start }, (_, i) => {
    const propNum = i + start;
    return query[`t${propNum}`];
  });
}

const query = {
  t0: 0,
  t1: 1,
  t2: 2,
  t3: 3,
  t4: 4,
  t5: 5,
  t6: 6,
  t7: 7,
  t8: 8,
  t9: 9,
}

console.log(fillArrayFromReq(query, 4, 7));
```

`Object.values` isn't entirely reliable because you can't always count on properties to have been added in order.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just aggregate and expand on the other nice answers. To get *all* the params values:

```js
const query = { a: 'a val', num: 4, t0: 't0 val', t1: 't1 val' };
let array = Object.values(query); // -> [ val1, val2, val3 ...]
console.log(array);

// or with [{key: value}] pairs
array = Object.keys(query)
  .map(key => ({[key]: query[key]})); // -> [ { param: val1 }, { anotherParam: val2 }, ... ] 
console.log(array);
```

But you had a different example, your params were starting with 't' followed by number:

```js
const query = { a: 'a val', num: 4, t0: 't0 val', t1: 't1 val' };
const array = Object.keys(query)
  .filter(key => /^t\d+$/.test(key)) // only take params whose keys start with a letter t, followed only by a number.
  .map(key => query[key]);
console.log(array);
```

Finally, you also had a limit, from t0 to t19:

```js
const query = { a: 'a val', num: 4, t0: 't0 val', t1: 't1 val', t19: 't19 val', t20: 't20 val' };
const array = Object.keys(query)
  .filter(key => /^t([0-9]|[01][0-9])$/.test(key))    // match keys starting with a t, followed by a number between 0 and 19
  .map(key => query[key]); // or .map(key => ({[key]: query[key]}))
console.log(array);
```

Or a bit more generic, take all `t<number> params`, but slice between `init` and `end`:

```js
const query = { a: 'a', num: 4, t0: 't0', t1: 't1' };
let init = 0;
let end = 19;
const array = Object.keys(query)
  .filter(key => /^t\d+$/.test(key))
  .map(key => query[key]) // or .map(key => ({[key]: query[key]}))
  .slice(init, end); 
console.log(array);
```

This doesn't check that the order is correct, e.g. if you skip t2, we go from t0 to t20, so once more:

```js
const query = { a: 'a', num: 4, t0: 't0', t1: 't1' };
let init = 0;
let end = 19;
const array = Object.keys(query)
  .filter(key => /^t\d+$/.test(key))
  .filter(key => {
    let num = parseInt(key.substring(1), 10);
    return num >= init && num <= end;
  })
  .map(key => query[key]); // or .map(key => ({[key]: query[key]}));
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Sometimes it can be an empty, value on the t[i].

Comment: Should not be a problem, it'll just be empty string.

Comment: /^t\d+$/.test is not a function

Comment: What environment are you working on? Try running (or copy-pasting directly to your JavaScript environment), it should work. I've edited all my examples so they are running here.