# Find() with array of ids not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, mongodb, mongoose

I have this route that I access from an AJAX GET call.

```
router.get("/index/fill/:id", function(req, res){
    var idArray = req.params.id;
    console.log(idArray); // OUTPUT = "4ed3ede8844f0f351100000c", "4ed3f117a844e0471100000d"
    User.find({'_id': {$in: idArray}}, function(err, foundUsers){
        console.log(foundUsers);
    });
});
```

Before the start of the find proccess the code throws me this error:

```
Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

But when i use `typeof` in `idArray[i]` it says that it is a string.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you providing an array as a URL parameter? Can you show an example of the request URL?

Comment: @AlanFriedman I add all the ids in a single string then i use .split() to create the array

Comment: Just asking because it’s unusual to pass an array that way. I’d recommend encoding the array as a query param, or if this endpoint is creating or modifying a resource, sending it in the body of a POST or PUT request.

Comment: @AlanFriedman You mean something like this:  `$.get("/index/fill/:id", {ids: arrayWithIds}, function(data){ ... })` ?

Comment: @BrunoPigatto No, @Alan is speaking about the way you send the ids by url `router.get("/index/fill/:id", function(req, res){` which is unusual.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47557828/5079258). You should be able to use [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) to format on the client. You would accept the array as a query param, not a URL parameter.

Comment: @AlanFriedman I did `getLink = "/index/fill/" + $.param({idsArray: ids});`, how do I access the param to use it in the route?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because your `ids` should be of type `ObjectId(...)`

Make sure you have imported `ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;`

You can try something like this:

```
router.get("/index/fill/:id", function (req, res) {
    var idArray = req.params.id;
    idArray = idArray.map(id => ObjectId(id));
    User.find({'_id': {$in: idArray}}, function (err, foundUsers) {
        console.log(foundUsers);
    });
});
```

or can also check `new ObjectId.createFromHexString(id)` in the map function if for some reason the straightforward object id creation doesn't work

Regarding the error:

> Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of
>   24 hex characters

It is thrown because `find` is expecting some `ObjectId` structure, which looks something like this:
`{'_id':'somehexof24char123456789'}`
but it doesn't find and `_id` which contains a required string so it throws this error.

I think you can find some documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field) about ObjectId

Comment: try to add in map `new ObjectId.createFromHexString(id)` and let me know if it works

Comment: Same error, ill try to use $.param and see what happens