# Pass array as query parameter in Swagger OpenApi 3.0

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, openapi

Ive currently given the below code to get an array of values as query paramters (in Node-express, nodejs v14.17 and OpenAPI version 3.0.1),

```
       - name: abcd
          description:  abcd
          in: query
          required: false
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
```

but it send the req as an array of values(type is `object`) only if there are atleast two of them. For a single value, the type is `string`.How to always get req as array itself?

[image]

For example,
if i give a single value say 
"Hello",
`console.log(typeof(req.query["abcd"]),req.query["abcd"])`
O/P: `string Hello`

but if i give "Hello" and "World",
O/P: `object ['Hello','World']`

Comment: Your array parameter definition is correct. Please post your controller code. What Node.js OpenAPI library do you use?

Comment: @Helen, hi, i have updated the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47557828/113116) explains, when a query parameter gets passed a single value, e.g. `?abcd=hello`, Express parses it as a regular value (i.e. string) rather than an array.

To pass a one-value array, you need to append `[]` at the end of the query parameter name, i.e. `?abcd[]=hello`. This means you need to change the parameter name in your OpenAPI file:

```yaml
       - name: abcd[]    # <------------
         description:  abcd
         in: query
         required: false
         schema:
           type: array
           items:
             type: string
```